# How to view webview cache in offline mode in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebView load website when online, load local file when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline)

I want to view website in cache ie in offline mode. I tried, but it fails in offline

showing `"www.google.com"` webpage not availabe. Generally the use of cache is to show the

webpage temporarily in offline. But I couldnt find the solution.Please help me. My code is as follows:

```
{ wt=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewt);
  wt.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
  wt.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
  wt.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  wt.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
  wt.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  wt.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
  wt.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  
  }
```

Comment: I've just answered a duplicate of your question over here:

[WebView load website when online, load local file when offline][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14671256/1427177