# one issue in RSS reader with offline reading

Tags: android, eclipse

i am building an RSS reader application in android via eclipse for my homework in my class.

i have a problem is: how to read RSS feeds while offline. it means that while online i can save some feeds for offline reading

can you help me or suggest me how to do that thanks very much

Comment: There is no way to access online content unless you save it offline. That's it :)

Comment: @LittleChild Right which is why they are asking for  a way to save feeds while online...

Comment: yes i am asking for a way (how to) save feeds while online and then while offline i can read it

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB 
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline 
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
} 

webView.loadUrl( "http://your.feed.url" );
```

This is how you will save the webpage offline. The `isNetworkAvailable()` looks like this:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() { 
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Source: [WebView load website when online, load local file when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline)