# How to load webView offline in android studio?

Tags: android, webview

I want to load a webpage in webView online and offline both when there is no network it should load a last updated webpage.

I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14671256/5484027) but this doesn't work for me. See the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC4nC.png

Here is my source code:

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {

WebView webView ;
ProgressBar progressBar;
protected File extStorageAppBasePath;
protected File extStorageAppCachePath;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);

    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview2);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    return view;
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

hey @Ayz Ali you are use `Fragment` and  `getapplicationContext` is use in `Activity`

you can use `getActivity` like this code

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize();
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getActivity().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
 }

 webView.loadUrl( "http://www.google.com" );
 }
```

Comment: hey @amit thanks for the answer I add your code but there is one error see this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/MCECAxH.png)

Comment: @AyzAli where is your `isNetwrokAvailable` method becoz you can not declare this function