# How to cache multiple URLs for a WebView Activity from Recycler View onClick

Tags: java, android, caching, android-recyclerview, android-webview

I have setup a `WebViewActivity` which gets the URL from the intent. I have setup an `onClickListener` for my `Recyclerview` which opens the `WebViewActivity` and loads the URL. However the `WebView` does not cache each an every page it opens. What changes should i make in the code?

WebViewActivity.java

```java
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Search");

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

ArticleAdapter.java

```java
public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ArticleViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "ArticleAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mlist;
    private String url;
    public ArticleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        mContext = context;
        mlist = list;
    }



    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: called");
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: GOT REQUEST CALLED===================");
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list, parent, false);
        return new ArticleViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ArticleViewHolder articleViewHolder, int i) {
        if(mlist.size()!=0){
           url = mlist.get(articleViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
           articleViewHolder.name.setText(url);
           articleViewHolder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url", articleViewHolder.name.getText());
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
        }
    }

    class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name;

        public ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write URL to the shared preference or file (with append mode), then whenever you need history just read the contents from the location

If you want cache web URLs then there is an option for `WebView`

Java code

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
websettings.setAppCachePath(getContext().getCacheDir().toString());
websettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
websettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

[this](https://coderanch.com/t/605255/Android/Mobile/Android-WebView-loading-page-cache) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479519/how-to-save-restore-webview-state) I have found useful, please refer these

Comment: But I have to cache the webview so that it can be used when the user is offline. Currently it stores only one page.

Comment: Then please go for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620588/cacheing-of-webpage-for-offline-use-android

Comment: Thank You!.. But is there a way to store multiple urls in cache

Comment: I have done that in the above code.. It only caches the first URL and not the all