# Does android webview content can be saved or cached for offline usage..?

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to add offline support for my app, when device is online app will display the load webpage in webview and same needs to be saved or cached for offline viewing.

When device is offline, same saved webview content shud be loaded to same webview. Webpage which are loaded has rich in content with css and images, all these needs to be saved or cached.

Please let me know if is there any api or lib to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline

Comment: thanks i will try out

Comment: Yes it worked with little change.. thanks lot