# Add update button in app to update the app info if availaible

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, intel-xdk

I'm using intel xdk to develop an app from my Class Routine. I was wondering how can I add update button ( in sidebar ) , such that if pressed will update the info  without manually updating from playstore?

Comment: Please specify what you have tried

Comment: can you elaborate @Sagar

Comment: Here is the link to what i want but I want to apply to intel xdk. How can I achieve that   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline