# Cache the last view of a page for offline mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, caching, offline-caching

I have a problem with my cache system for android 
and what i want is to cache my last view for android and open it in offline mode but in case of online want the live page not the cached one
if we take any website of price as an example like this one
http://www.oil-price.net/
and this my java class code

```
public class Petroleum_price extends Fragment {


    public Petroleum_price() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    Context context;
    WebView mwebView;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_petroleum_price, container, false);
        context = container.getContext();
        mwebView = new WebView(context);
        mwebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mwebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getActivity().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
        mwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mwebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
            mwebView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
        }

        mwebView.loadUrl( "http://www.oil-price.net/" );
        return v;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for your `WebView` implementation

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 10 * 1024 * 1024 );
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) {
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}
webView.loadUrl( "http://www.google.com" );

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

and use this codes in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

based on the answer of [WebView load website when online, load local file when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline)

Comment: these code is implement in my code but doesn't cache, it open the page when i am online but if offline doesn't open any thing.
and thanks a lot for your response

Comment: my code is in fragment not activity is there problem with it ?

Comment: test code again i changed it. no i don't think that causes problem @AsemAbd-elnaser