# How to cache (fully) web page from webview?

Tags: android, caching, webview, browser-cache

I need to make preCaching of web page (to some local storage) when there is internet connection and when user will be ready - show it in own webview (user may be "ready" in some future session, not right now).

Looks like rather trivial task, but I still cant find any workable solution...

Will be glad any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline

Comment: as I said - I still didn't find any workable solution! Thanks for you link, i already tried it before - still not work.
any other ideas?