# Mobile Application based on the website

Tags: android, html, wordpress, webview, local

Im new with Android. My task is to create a mobile application based on a responsive WordPress website. I would like to be able to download some of the content of this site. Website uses HTTPS. In the first, most primitive version, I tried to use WebView. 
I wanted to use the following: [WebView load website when online, load local file when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline). 
Unfortunately, only the white page appeared and nothing more. In the case of "Google.com link" a page has been loaded in an external browser (Oreo Android).

Any suggestion how should I start? The easiest way would be to download an HTML page or have access to files on the server. Unfortunately, I do not have that access.

Comment: Check if you have given INTERNET permission in android when white page appeared.

Comment: Yup, there is Internet permission in AndroidManifest. As I said when I trying `webView.loadUrl("http://google.com")` it works fine, but when I change it to my https link then white page appeared.

Comment: Okey, Something was wrong. Now it works with HTTPS, but cannot log in via external site... Anyway I think I should create structure from http file to have all working as offline version

Answer (score 0):

As always -1 without even trying to help....
As I said load from cache when Internet is disabled not working. Work only WebView (without login, because CORS). So how should I face it?