# how to make a Webview Directly to an offline page When the internet connection is slow or signal loss

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an Android project using a webview but there are some conditions that I want to make:

-How direct to page offline when the internet is connected but slow connection?

-how do you go to the page offline when the internet connects but the signal is lost?

which I can make only when there is no connection, direct to the offlne page ..

thank you

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline

Comment: if you want show to notif the apps is offline or no internet connection. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624437